# Unable to insert the column in hbase properly

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, bigdata

I'm trying to insert a column into a hbase table using the following command.

**put 'CHANNEL_METRICS.HBASE_TEST','201801191150-201801191159','cf_test:CTRR::ERR-E1::EUSCode-AA::MTR-X',2**

when I do scan 'CHANNEL_METRICS.HBASE_TEST'. I only see the following

**201801191150-201801191159                                   column=cf_test:CTRR, timestamp=1516649284828, value=2**

Should I use any escape characters to insert the rest of the string following CTRR? Why am I not able to see the full string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shell commands do not support column qualifiers containing colon (:)

Plase check this jira bug :

[HBASE-13788](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-13788?attachmentOrder=desc)